# Using iframe-resizer to properly resize in mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, iframe-resizer

I'm using iframe-resizer to refit the content of one page inside another. I got it working well for desktop browser viewing, but cannot make my iframe resize on mobile in my realistic demo. I tested on a second server too with a different page design for another real-world demo. Both didn't resize. I'm testing in iOS Safari and Chrome. I set up a simple test case and it worked how it's supposed to, unlike my two demo pages. Obviously, something in the source of the demo parent pages is preventing the intended functionality. Can someone please help me find what is preventing these demo pages from resizing properly in mobile? I figure if two random sites to test this on cause a problem, it is likely that my clients installing this widget will also frequently encounter this problem and I need to be able to offer a remedy.

Test case (good): http://healthfitchiro.com/wp-content/iframe.html

Realistic demo (bad): http://healthfitchiro.com/alternate-login

Comment: I don't enough reputation to post more than 2 links in the post:
Realistic demo (bad): http://tckayakfishing.com/test-page

Realistic demo: (good): https://www.healthfitcorpwell.com/hfcwlc/

Comment: It seems like the website on the bad example is not responsive. 
I guess you have to resize the container gradually in order for the iframe to resize itself.

Comment: @KonstantinosKoletsas What would I need to do to accomplish that?

Comment: First of all, it's not going to take just a few minutes and it's not an easy process. You will actually make your layout viewable to almost every device. Here is a nice introduction guide https://dzone.com/articles/using-csshtml-make-responsive. Alternatively, you can tweak your container's css by using `width: 100%` and setting the `max-width` to the desired pixels. However the second solution is a completely bad approach.

Comment: I removed `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />` from the `<head>` element and now it appears in the default view, which displays the iframe normally (and the webpage at full size). Is this a bad idea?

Comment: It's totally up to you ! You can read about the viewport meta tag here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag. It actually provides directives for the browser's behavior.

Comment: Since this is a widget that is going to be installed on various clients' pages that I cannot guarantee are designed to be correctly responsive, is there a way to force the iframe to resize in the way I need to if necessary?